# Fire action when UIImageView animation is done

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview

In the world of delegates and detectors, I'm having trouble finding a method for detecting if an animation I am playing is playing or not. Once the animation is done, I want the UIImageView to fade out and remove itself from its superview.

I am using the common `animationImages` value of the UIImageView.

Right now, I have a once-per-second looped checker looking at the UIImageView's `animates` value, and determining if it's still playing.

But this feels a bit excessive, so does anyone know a smarter method of doing this, possibly with custom classing the UIImageView if thats what it takes ?

Comment: What kind of animation you are doing with `UIImageView`? Are you using  UIImageView's  `animationImages` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using  UIImageView's `animationImages` property, then you might need to follow Eugene's solution.

Immediately after calling the UIImageView's `startAnimating` method, you start an NSTimer which has to be fired after `animationDuration`. In the fired timer method, you could hide the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting you're `UIImageView`'s `animationDuration` property, why don't you try creating a timer which will fire after that same duration and set your `UIImageView` hidden in some method?